# Save Modified Phone Number to ContactList at respective index Android

Tags: android, android-contacts

I successfully retrieved the position and phone number from my contact list. Now i need to save this number in my ContactList by modifying the orignal number. I am blocked at this step. please give me a hint example type position = 2 and number = 3049393.  Here is my complete code.

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    public static final int PICK_CONTACT    = 1;

    TextView txt_contacts;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        // this opens the activity. note the  Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT
        // and the intent.setType
        ((Button)findViewById(R.id.btn_contacts)).setOnClickListener( new OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                // user BoD suggests using Intent.ACTION_PICK instead of .ACTION_GET_CONTENT to avoid the chooser
                Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
                // BoD con't: CONTENT_TYPE instead of CONTENT_ITEM_TYPE
                intent.setType(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.CONTENT_ITEM_TYPE);
                startActivityForResult(intent, 1);  
                txt_contacts =(TextView)findViewById(R.id.txt_contacts);
            }
        });
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.activity_main, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        if (data != null) {
            Uri uri = data.getData();

            if (uri != null) {
                Cursor c = null;
                try {
                    c = getContentResolver().query(uri, new String[]{ 
                                ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.NUMBER,  
                                ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.TYPE },
                            null, null, null);

                    if (c != null && c.moveToFirst()) {
                        String number = c.getString(0);
                        int type = c.getInt(1);
                        showSelectedNumber(type, number);
                    }
                } finally {
                    if (c != null) {
                        c.close();
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }


    public void showSelectedNumber(int type, String number) {

        String new_num = 0+number;
        txt_contacts.setText(new_num);

    }




public void updateContact() {
        try {
            ArrayList<ContentProviderOperation> ops = new ArrayList<ContentProviderOperation>();

            ops.add(ContentProviderOperation.newUpdate(Data.CONTENT_URI)
                .withSelection(Data.RAW_CONTACT_ID + " = ?", new String[] {mRawContactId})
                .withSelection(Data._ID + " = ?", new String[] {mDataId})
                .withValue(Data.MIMETYPE, Email.CONTENT_ITEM_TYPE)
                .withValue(Data.DATA1, mEmail)
                .withValue(Email.TYPE, Email.TYPE_HOME)
                .build());
            getContentResolver().applyBatch(ContactsContract.AUTHORITY, ops);
            mResult.setText("Updated");
        } catch (Exception e) {
            // Display warning
            Log.w("UpdateContact", e.getMessage());
            for(StackTraceElement ste : e.getStackTrace()) {
                Log.w("UpdateContact", "\t" + ste.toString());
            }
            Context ctx = getApplicationContext();
            int duration = Toast.LENGTH_SHORT;
            Toast toast = Toast.makeText(ctx, "Update failed", duration);
            toast.show();
        }
    }       


    }
```

**Update :**

public void showSelectedNumber(int type, String number) {

```
    String new_num = 0+number;
    System.out.println("Display name:"+ number);


    ContentValues _changed_values=new ContentValues();

    _changed_values.put(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.NUMBER,new_num);
            getContentResolver().update(uri,_changed_values,ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone._ID+"=?",
    new String[]{Integer.toString(type)});


            // If you want to change the number 

    txt_contacts.setText(new_num);

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ContentValues _changed_values=new ContentValues();

// If you want to change the number 
_changed_values.put(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.NUMBER,"mention number");

//where you have to change 
_id= mention id of that particular contact

getContentResolver().update(uri,_changed_values,ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.ID+"=?",
                                new String[]{_id} }

Comment: can you provide me with an example

Comment: check my updated question please. i adapt the change to my class but what is ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.ID ? getting an error at this line -> ID cannot be resolved or is not a field

Comment: getContentResolver().update(uri,_changed_values,ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone._ID+"=?",
new String[]{_id} } is proper i guess. ur missing an underscore there

Comment: yes but it doesn't update the phone number getContentResolver().update(uri,_changed_values,
    ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone._ID+"=?", new String[]{Integer.toString(type)});

Comment: i write that code in notepad i dont have an eclipse in my lapy